# On double dual of C* algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Can anyone provide examples of double dual of $C^{*}$-algebras except $K(\mathcal{H})$, commutative cases?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every C*-algebra of course provides an example but I suppose the examples for which the double dual is identifiable as something well known are essentially the ones you mentioned, plus the finite dimensional ones.  Perhaps it is also worth pointing out that no infinite dimensional algebra is reflexive as a Banach space.

Comment: The double dual of a $C^*$-algebra almost never admits a nice description. This is a very wild beast!

Comment: Further to what @QuantumSpace said, for infinite dimensional commutative $A$ the double dual doesn't have a nice description. I understand with $A=C([0,1])$ it can be identified with a proper subset of the bounded functions on $[0,1]$.